# unique_ptr, nullptr and supporting gcc 4.5.x and 4.6.x

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, unique-ptr, nullptr

I am working on a library with two different end users one of which is using gcc 4.5.3 and the other just moved to gcc 4.6.3.  The library uses the new C++11 smart pointers (in particular unique_ptr) and compiles fine on gcc 4.5.3.  However, between those two versions gcc began supporting nullptr so the API of unique_ptr changed to match the standard more closely.  In doing so now the following code went from fine to ambiguous

```
unique_ptr up( new int( 30 ) );
...
if( up == 0 ) // ambiguous call now to unique_ptr(int) for 0
```

Is there a clean (viz., next sentence) way to change the if statement above so that it works both with and without nullptr?  I'd like to avoid a configure check and then a macro like the following (which I think will work) if possible

```
#if defined NULLPOINTER_AVAILABLE
  #define NULLPTR (nullptr)
#else
  #define NULLPTR (0)
#endif
```

or is this the only way to get the behavior I am looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What errors did you hit?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
int main() {
 using namespace std;
 unique_ptr<int> up( new int( 30 ) );
 if (up == 0)
     cout << "nullptr!\n";
 else cout << "bam!\n";
}
```

compiles fine with with `g++ -std=c++0x -Wall nullptr.cpp -o nullptr` (gcc 4.6.2).

Also, go through [N2431](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2431.pdf) paper by Stroustrup and Sutter on `nullptr`where a similar usage (comparison with `0`) is explicitly listed in one of the examples.

Comment: You are right that your example works (and mine in the problem statement for that matter) so it must have something to do with the types I am actually using (I am not using "int" but a templated class).  I'll see if I can find a better example that causes what I am seeing and if not I'll mark this correct.

Comment: @bpw1621: I'm sure this is something to do with the actual type. Are they *MoveConstructible* and *MoveAssignable*? You can check this with the appropriate `type_traits` members such as `is_move_constructible`.

Comment: If they are types that are either does that cause the ambiguity?  I did see the move constructor in the overload set I think.

Comment: @bpw1621: From N3337: §20.7.1/5 *5 Each object of a type U instantiated from the unique_ptr template specified in this subclause has the strict
ownership semantics, specified above, of a unique pointer. In partial satisfaction of these semantics, each
such U is MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but is not CopyConstructible nor CopyAssignable.
The template parameter T of unique_ptr may be an incomplete type.* You may want to check your types again with this in mind. Also, make sure your version of gcc supports `unique_ptr` (this is obvious but ...)